# Failed to execute 'getImageData' due to cross-origin when loading image from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, cross-domain, webgl, google-cloud-storage, pixi.js

We have image hosted on Google Cloud and get an link for it on the server-side using

```
new GcsAppIdentityServiceUrlSigner().getSignedUrl("GET", path))
```

And it looks like

```
 https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<folder>/image.JPG?GoogleAccessId=<project>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1400686814&Signature=xPRKGFM01CkV9J4p0kzqMYmLGO1QJkFfoW7EaG%2FYfVcCZIgKCoflCE2E5kHlzG%2FZapjgQrkx%2BBEm%2FGmt2ZbezvW2nNm3KLuJFy%2BuaA%2BO1HNPdTtzuhU9q9yjioUYSA0fb%2BpnOaNHQVmLfLOvjj84l0QIKrCOFsnzfuMUwV7ZuVo%3D
```

We've configured CORS for bucket as this described in this [link](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<CorsConfig>
    <Cors>
        <Origins>
            <Origin>*</Origin>
        </Origins>
        <Methods>
            <Method>GET</Method>
        </Methods>
        <ResponseHeaders>
            <ResponseHeader>Content-Type</ResponseHeader>
        </ResponseHeaders>
    </Cors>
</CorsConfig>

gsutil cors set cors.xml gs://<bucket>
```

Then it worked for AssetLoader:

```
var viewport = $(".viewport"),
    renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(null, null, null, true),
    container = new PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer(),
    stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xffffff, true);


var imageLink = "...";
var loader = new PIXI.AssetLoader([]);
loader.crossorigin = true;

var texture;
loader.onComplete = function () {
    texture = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(imageLink);
    container.addChild(currentTexture);
    stage.addChild(container);
    viewport.append(renderer.view);
};
loader.load();
```

But caused an error 
    function createSpite() {
        var canvas = $('').get(0),
            ctx2D = canvas.getContext("2d");

```
    image.onload = function () {
        // ...
        var imgData = ctx2D.getImageData(minX, minY, imgWidth, imgHeight); // causes an error
        // ...
    };
    image.src = imageLink;

}
```

The error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on
'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with PIXI, but I might expect that the ultimate cause would be that the image object's `crossorigin` property is not being set to "anonymous" or "use-credentials".

You could test this by trying to directly load the image in a cross-origin style on a test page. There's a good example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image